# Predictions with non-normal explanatory and response variables

Tags: prediction

I'm trying to work out if I can make predictions with the data I have. Both the explanatory and response variables are fairly non-normally distributed continual variables.

I'm a bit new at this and am working with R Commander, my initial thoughts would be that I should use either Spearman's rho or Kendall's tau to see if one of these variables can be used to predict the other.

Would I be correct in thinking that Spearman's rho or Kendall's tau are appropriate with non-normalised data of a reasonably large sample size, as opposed to say regression or Pearson's correlation?

I've applied log, square root and reciprocal transformations but the results are still not normally distributed.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you show sone density plots or pairs plots?  Also, why do you think you can predict? I mean, just throw it in to your prediction model, compute crossvalidated errors, and see how well you are doing

Comment: Thanks for the reply Georg! I'm really new to this so hopefully this is the correct plot http://i.imgur.com/AvHKMzL.jpg . 
Part of this exercise is to find out if a reasonable prediction can be made, I'm not certain that it can. 
I'm not working with a prediction model, just the basics of what's in r commander.

Comment: For most analyses the distribution of your explanatory (/independent) variables is not subject to any assumptions and the distribution of the raw response (dependent) variable is similarly not subject to assumptions (though the conditional distribution may carry assumptions when performing tests of calculating intervals). Many posts on site discuss this. Try some searches first then please clarify by indicating what you're trying to find out and perhaps show us what you're looking at.

Comment: Thanks for the reply Glen! I may be mistaken but from what I've read normality is required for a regression using sum of least squares, or Pearson's product-moment correlation, these are I believe the more informative tests that I'm so far familiar with. It's my understanding that normality of the distribution isn't required when n > 30 for comparing a continuous variable across multiple categories but I've so far not read that non-normal continual / non-normal continual can be used with the above tests. I'm trying to determine if correlation / prediction is possible, and if so how to do it.

Comment: Can you clarify if you are interested in prediction or in inference?  For prediction, you essentially don't need any assumptions whatsoever -- just throw it into your favorite prediction model (random forest, SVM, GAM, neural net, glmnet, ...) and compute cross-validation error to see if it improves predictions compared to a sample mean.  For inference, you do need to care about distribution assumptions, but about conditional distribution of y | X , not about y or X alone. So X and y can be non-normal (and in general are non-normal), as long as y | X is normal your basic OLS is good to go.